# How do I configure Micronaut to get better performance using Reactor

Tags: netty, micronaut

I have defined two HTTP GET APIs /test-mono and /test-no-mono, both are exactly same except /test-mono is using Mono return type. HelloControllerSpec tests both APIs 1000 times using Thread pool of 100, and /test-no-mono takes 45 seconds but /test-mono takes more than 4 minutes, why? Looks like in the default concurrency configuration of /test-no-mono is way better than /test-mono.

Full code is at https://github.com/soumitrak/micronaut-server

```
@Controller("/")
class HelloController {

    @Get("test-mono/{id}", produces = arrayOf(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
    fun test_mono(id: String): Mono<String> {
        Thread.sleep(4000)
        return Mono.just("Hello World! $id")
    }

    @Get("test-no-mono/{id}", produces = arrayOf(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
    fun test_no_mono(id: String): String {
        Thread.sleep(4000)
        return "Hello World! $id"
    }
}
```

$ ./gradlew clean test

> Task :test

sk.test.server.HelloControllerSpec STANDARD_OUT

```
09:37:32.473 [Test worker] INFO  i.m.context.env.DefaultEnvironment - Established active environments: [test]
```

sk.test.server.HelloControllerSpec > using Mono STANDARD_OUT

```
09:37:34.262 [Test worker] INFO  sk.test.server.HelloControllerSpec - Tests using mono
09:41:46.972 [Test worker] INFO  sk.test.server.HelloControllerSpec - Done tests using mono
```

## Tests run in > 4 minutes

sk.test.server.HelloControllerSpec > without Mono STANDARD_OUT

```
09:41:46.975 [Test worker] INFO  sk.test.server.HelloControllerSpec - Tests without mono
09:42:27.216 [Test worker] INFO  sk.test.server.HelloControllerSpec - Done tests without mono
```

## Same tests in 45 seconds.

What is the reason "/test-mono" is slow and how do I improve performance of this API?

Comment: Possibly because your requests to `/test-mono` are being handled on the event loop thread (which they are supposed to be).  I think the default value for `nThreads` is the number of processors times 2.  You can change that value with something like `micronaut.executors.io.nThreads=50`.

Comment: Jeff is right. Netty handles IO/NIO differently. NIO has threadSize equal to docker processor ex: if you are running your server in quadCore processor then only 4 threads are allotted. For IO default threadSize would be 200. So IO or Blocking API is faster.

Answer (score 0):

Your test scenario is unrealistic. You should never block the event loop, which is what you're doing when calling Thread.sleep. The blocking code is performing better because it has more threads. Adding more threads isn't the answer to achieve better performance in a realistic scenario.